# Accessing Windows 10 Setting Panel

Tags: windows, windows-10

Today I installed the Windows 10 upgrade.  I wanted to modify the default browser options to change the default browser.  A note I found online pointed to modifying this option by choosing the Settings option from the new “Start” like menu.   So on the new “Start” like menu one of the options is labeled Setting and as a gear like icon next to it.  When this item is selected it appears to flash open and close immediately.  If I open the Action Center with the Windows-A key and choose Setting from the Action Center which is located in the lower right, the behavior is the same.  Within the Start menu the setting option is titled just “Settings” and in the Action Center it is called “All Settings”.  I am looking to find a way to actually see the “Settings” panel.  I found other ways to change the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug. Both ways of accessing the settings, although labeled differently, lead to the same place. I just upgraded today myself after running the Insider Preview for a few weeks, and everything works as intended. (I had to reinstall Windows 7, activate it, then install 10 again to get the license recognized.)

This is what the settings panel looks like:

[image]

You *should* be able to install a fresh install of Windows 10 now that your hardware is tied to the activation service. Keyword: Should.

Comment: How would I go about installing a fresh version of Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

I connected with Microsoft Support via a chat session.  The short story is the Tech connected to my computer and download some tools and fixed the problem.
Support-LogMeInRescue.exe
CSEmerg6775a.disg.cab

I'm good now!

Later in the day I found this link:  http://maddinenirahul.blogspot.com/2015/07/windows-10-settings-do-not-open.html

This seems to be a know problem with some Windows 10 install.